# Machine learning algorithm for validating a state sequence

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, reinforcement-learning, state-space-models

I am developing a machine learning algorithm to validate a markov chain sequence.
Currently I have :
 1. A ngram predictor which predicts the next state from the state history and will check whether this state occurs in the next time step.
 2. A function to check the time spent on each state and to compare it with the previously known time required in that particular state.(But time spent in a state may vary and may not be same to the previously known time. So I am stuck here also)
 3. A function which compares the previous state with a known state sequence and tells whether it's a valid state change or not

I need to use all these information to validate that the state change occurred is a valid state change so that i can use this information for my further application.For eg: íf any invalid state change is detected it should give a bad validation result from above information and should give a reward(+ or -) based on the validation result to the next validation checking step
Which algorithm is best suited for this kind of application?

Comment: Doesn't your third routine already give you the binary "valid", "not valid" output?  It might be helpful to know what your overall problem is - are you designing the chain?  It sounds like you are asking how to assign the rewards based on the information from your first two routines. If you already know the rewards, then I would look into Multi-armed bandits and their fixed-budget variants.

Comment: My  Problem is :I have an algorithm that detects the current state of a human from lot of sensors.Now I want to model a second  algorithm that detects the correctness of the output of the first algorithm based on the state history.This is done  to reconfirm that the output of the first algorithm is correct and follows a sequence .This algorithm should also consider the time spent in a state.If i only consider my third routine it may say sequence is correct even if i spent 1 sec in it.So it should be intelligent enough to say why i spent only 1 sec based on my state history  and validate it.